# Is there any mothod to judge whether a image is one HDR image or not?

Tags: hdr

everybody, i am doing one thing than i want to judge whether one image is a HDR image, if you have any ideas, please shared it with me , thank you ! my friends.

Comment: Checking that there are no **extended** areas of either 0x000000 (underexposure) or 0xFFFFFF (superexposure)?

Comment: Or, experiment yourself... with data. Get a large number of truly HDR images and sample the brightness of every pixel, then create a histogram. You should see that HDR images use a wide range of brightness values

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If AVIF file is tagged with PQ or HLG transfer functions it is HDR. You can use exiftool on these samples to check for that. https://github.com/AOMediaCodec/av1-avif/tree/master/testFiles/Netflix/avif